# how to get the first cell value of a hierarchy telerk grid view

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

i'm using *telerik grid view* and i want to get the first element of the child

i know how to do it for a telerik grid view  but for t's child i have no idea

it should be something like this

```
        GetCustomerId = radgridview.EditorControl
                          .Rows[radgridview.SelectedIndex].Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
```

the problem is that after `radgridview` there is no `selectedindex`

what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all rows from the first level of hierarchy (template 0):

```
radGridView1.Templates[0].Rows
```

This will give you all child rows for a given parent row (Rows[0]):

```
radGridView1.Rows[0].ChildRows
```

To access the first cell in the first child row of the first parent row:

```
radGridView1.Rows[0].ChildRows[0].Cells["ColumnName"].Value
```